# Invalid Column Index in Stored Proc call with Out parameter

Tags: java, callable-statement

Invalid Column Index error is being thrown on get object.
Java Code where the Proc is being called and parameters are being set:

```
        public Object[] order(HttpServletRequest request,
              String userId,
              String tName,
              String aCodes,
              String aFinCodes,
              String oType,
              int iBase,
              String cFinCodes
             ) throws xyzSqlException{

        Connection conn = null;
        CallableStatement cstmt=null;
        ResultSet rsTempHead = null;
        ResultSet rsTempDetails = null;
        int notdisplayedRows = 0;
        Object[] oTempList = null;

                        ds = getDataSource(installBase);

                        try
                        {
                            conn = ds.getConnection();

                            OrdEntDTO tempDetailsDTO= null;

                                cstmt = conn.prepareCall("{call get_temp_details (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)}");

                            cstmt.setString(1,userId);
                            cstmt.setString(2,tName);
                            cstmt.setString(3,aCodes);
                            cstmt.setString(4,Utility.convertSQLStringIN(aFinCodes,","));
                            cstmt.setString(5,oType);
                            cstmt.registerOutParameter(6, -10);
                            cstmt.registerOutParameter(7, -10);
                            cstmt.registerOutParameter(8,Types.NUMERIC);
                            cstmt.setString(9,Utility.convertSQLStringIN(cFinCodes,","));
                            rsTemplateHeader =(ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(6);
                            rsTemplateDetails =(ResultSet)cstmt.getObject(7);
                            notdisplayedRows = cstmt.getInt(8);
                            logger.debugMsg("The notdisplayedRows " + notdisplayedRows);
                                int listIndex = 0;
                                if(rsTemplateDetails != null)
                                {
                                    oTempList = new Object[501] ;
                                }
}
```

The error:

```
[3/9/17 17:23:43:771 IST] 00000030 SystemOut     O 2017-03-09 17:23:43,771
FATAL dao.OEntryDAO - Sql       Exception Occured :- Invalid column index
[3/9/17 17:23:43:831 IST] 00000030 SystemOut     O 2017-03-09 17:23:43,824   ERROR dao.OEntryDAO - Sql Exception   Occured :- Invalid column index
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column index
at   oracle.jdbc.driver.SQLStateMapping.newSQLException(SQLStateMapping.java:70)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.newSQLException(DatabaseError.java:133)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:199)
at  oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:263)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:271)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.DatabaseError.throwSqlException(DatabaseError.java:445)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatement.getObject(OracleCallableStatement.java:1571)
at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleCallableStatementWrapper.getObject(OracleCallableStatementWrapper.java:815)
at com.ibm.ws.rsadapter.jdbc.WSJdbcCallableStatement.getObject(WSJdbcCallableStatement.java:782)
at dao.ODAO.order(OEntryDAO.java:1762)
at action.OEntryTempAction.execute(OEntryTempAction.java:184)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.processActionPerform(RequestProcessor.java:419)
at org.apache.struts.action.RequestProcessor.process(RequestProcessor.java:224)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.process(ActionServlet.java:1194)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.doGet(ActionServlet.java:414)
at Servlet.doGet(WebpartsServlet.java:42)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:718)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:831)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1661)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.service(ServletWrapper.java:1602)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain.doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:113)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.filter.WebAppFilterChain._doFilter(WebAppFilterChain.java:80)
```

Procedure:

```
   CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE get_temp_details (userid                  IN       VARCHAR2,
    tname            IN       VARCHAR2,
    acode              IN       VARCHAR2,
    afincode           IN       VARCHAR2,
    otype               IN       VARCHAR2,
    refcur1                 OUT      sys_refcursor,
    refcur2                 OUT      sys_refcursor,
    temp_ord_status   OUT      NUMBER,
    cFinCodes      IN       VARCHAR2
)
```

what can be the reason behind the error? If needed more code will be provided.

Comment: without (Resultset) it is throwing error; it is casting here

Comment: https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/jdbc-callablestatement-stored-procedure-cursor-example/